# trapezoidal vs sinusoidal commutation

Tags: brushless-motor

How do you know if a commercial driver is working with trapezoidal or sinusoidal commutation? If you measure the 3-phase voltage applied to the PMSM by means of an oscilloscope, will you see a difference?

Comment: In a block commutation , the phase shift between each phases is 120degrees. However the diagram of block commutation shows only 60 deg phase shift. Does anybody know if a 60deg phase shift could commutate the BLDC correctly?

Comment: Please start a new thread if you have a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm reasonably sure that the sinusoidal wave will look like a sign wave, and that the trapezoidal wave will look more square-ish. The image below explains it better:

[image: Trapezoidal vs Sinusoidal waves]

Comment: The trapezoidal waveforms don't look right. It is block commutation, which means that for each phase, it is positive for 2 states, tri-state for 1 state, negative for 2 states, and tri-state again for 1. When it is tri-state, the back-EMF varies so that it looks trapezoidal. Your diagram seems to show the $V_A$ at max for only 1 commutation state in each cycle